# How do i get params in nexjs middleware?

Tags: next.js

I have a middleware that triggers on every request. How do I get the id in the url?
if it were like this

http://localhost:3000/dash/profile/103848028402840
http://localhost:3000/dash/home/103848028402840;
http://localhost:3000/dash/notification/103848028402840

I can't split profile/ because the next time the middleware runs, it wouldn't be profile, but home.

and [middleware].js will not work either right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to use [Next Catch all route feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)

you need to change your filename to `[...middleware].js` as [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) will help you get access to the data in url.

then in page you can do like

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function CustomPage() {
    const router= useRouter()
    console.log(router.query)
    const {params = []} = router.query
   // you will get all the data in params array and last index will be id
    console.log(params[2])  
}
```

Comment: Oh! thank you, you are a hero! ⚡⚡